# Is there a name for these kinds of polynomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, terminology, characters

I've come across the following polynomials in my research and I am wondering if they have a name or if there is very much known about them:

\begin{equation}
F_{\chi}(T) = \sum_{a = 1}^{n-1} \chi(a)T^a
\end{equation}

where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character of conductor $n$.  The closest thing I can find on these are the Fekete polynomials (this is the special case where $\chi$ is the Legendre symbol and $n$ is a prime number) but nothing for general Dirichlet characters.  Thanks in advance for any information you might be able give me.

Comment: Good morning! There are several keywords that may apply here. If $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character mod. $p$ of order $k$ and $T=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$, you have a "Gauss sum" (cf. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183548292); I believe that in such a case, the phrase "hybrid character sum" applies, too. If $T$ is not of the aforementioned form, an expression that may apply to your $F_{\chi}(T)$ is "twisted character sum".

Comment: Don't know it this helps, but these polynomials appear in the definiton of generalized Bernoulli numbers and polynomials.See for example Lang's "Cyclotomic Fields (vols I and II combined)", page 37.